# Can we create file/zipfile as InputStream without a temporary file in java

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream

I need to create a test where I need to pass an `InputStream` as input which would be a zipfile. Is there a way we can create `InputStream` directly instead creating in memory / local file copies so that stream can be used for testing.

Comment: Are you looking for [`ByteArrayInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)?

Comment: Thanks slaw for your response . bytearrayinputstream should also help . Is ther a way we can create a temporary zipfile using bytearrayInputStream without an inmemory file?

Comment: Use a ZipOutputStream() to write to a ByteArraoyOutputSream. You can then get the byte array out of the ByteArrayOutputStream and create a ByteArrayInputStream. You can read from this stream using a ZipInputStream.

Comment: my question is..  is there a way we can create zipInputStream/InputStream/FileInputStream without creating File ?? new ZipInputStream(theFile) this is the way we need to create ZipInputStream , but if you canhelp me with some sample code or any utility already availble would help . Thanks for response

Comment: the requirement I have is , there is a Junit where in which I need to Invoke a rest API which takes Zip file as Input . 
 So I want to create this Zip file with some dummy data hardcoded in test . so for this I want to create InputStream and send it thru rest api to validate my test Instead creating ondisk zipfile if there is a way for this .

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly you want to create a ZIP file in-memory (i.e. not on disk) from hard-coded data. This is certainly possible using the following classes:

- [`java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)
- [`java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)
- [`java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html)
- [`java.util.zip.ZipEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html)

Here's an example:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Destination of the ZIP file (an in-memory byte array)
    ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    /*
     * Write the ZIP file. This creates a single entry named "file.txt"
     * with "Hello, World!" as its contents.
     */
    try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(boas)) {
      zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("file.txt"));
      zos.write("Hello, World!".getBytes());
      zos.closeEntry();
    }

    // Create an InputStream to read the raw bytes of the ZIP file
    ByteArrayInputStream bois = new ByteArrayInputStream(boas.toByteArray());

    /*
     * The following writes the ZIP file to disk, specifically to a file named "test.zip"
     * in the working directory. The purpose of this is to allow you to run the code
     * and see a tangible result (i.e. lets you inspect the resulting ZIP file). Obviously
     * you would not do this in your own code since you want to avoid writing the ZIP file
     * to disk.
     * 
     * Note: Will fail if the file already exists.
     */
    Files.copy(bois, Path.of("test.zip"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Elaborating on some of the answers found above let me describe a situation I encountered and how I solved it. I encountered a situation where I receive files that are PGP encrypted (.pgp, .asc etc) so I had to decrypt the file (.txt) itself be passing it into a stream reader to parse the line entries. Instead of saving the decrypted file as temporarily file in the file system before reading it in to parse the entries. I did it in memory as follows.

I had a function which pipes the InputStream into a ByteArrayOutputStream (instead of FileOutputStream, retrieve the byte array and initialize it as ByteArrayInputStream and printed out each entry with a reader

```
InputStream encFileIn = new FileInputStream("some_encrypted_file.asc");
byte[] decryptFile = util.decryptFile(encFileIn);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(decryptFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
reader.lines().forEach(f -> System.out.println(f));
```

Here are some code snippets on piping the InputStream inside my decrypt function which may not be applicable to you as I am working with PGP files. So you maybe try to directly instantiate a ByteArrayInputStream as is

```
public static void pipeAll(InputStream inStr, OutputStream outStr)
    throws IOException
{
    byte[] bs = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int numRead;
    while ((numRead = inStr.read(bs, 0, bs.length)) >= 0)
    {
        outStr.write(bs, 0, numRead);
    }
}

public static byte[] readAll(InputStream inStr)
    throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    pipeAll(inStr, buf);
    return buf.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Why did you waste memory on a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and a `ByteArrayInputStream` when you already had an `InputStream`? You could have decrypted file directly from the original `InputStream` via a `CipherInputStream` and provided that to the `InputStreamReader`. And none of this addresses the question that was asked, other than by repeating the methods of prior answers in an irrelevant way.

Comment: Your suggestion to use the CipherInputStream is more efficient and straight to the point, thanks for that. Problem is I am using the bouncycastle implementation of openpgp (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpg-jdk15on/1.68) and internally it doesn't implement the java.security.key interface for their secret keys. I know how to initialize it without bouncycastle but I prefer to use this library for various reasons such as other external programs that would scan our applications for vulnerabilities and recommend upgrade versions. Sorry for the repeat, I jumped the gun.